# Re-enable accidentally disabled Windows 10 Boot Manager

Tags: windows-10, boot, bootloader

A friend of mine, not fully conscious of what he was doing, accidentally disabled the Boot Manager.

This happened after an update gone bad, after which he was presented with Windows Advanced Boot Options and messed with the abovementioned option.
Now this is what appears every time he turns on the computer (see image below)

He hadn't previously unlocked the laptop from Windows, so he has no way to access the BIOS. Nor he has the Recovery disks any longer.

Is there any other way he can re-enable the Boot Manager, or in any way recover his system?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution depends on what exactly occurred:

1. **If the BCD store was removed or the boot files corrupted/removed:**

   1. Boot to WinPE/WinRE

      - **WinPE:** Windows install media

        - Press **<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>** to open a terminal
      - **WinRE:** Windows recovery
   2. Issue the following commands:

      1. `BootRec /FixMBR`
      2. `BootRec /FixBoot` *(**BIOS only**, not UEFI)*
      3. `BootRec /RebuildBCD`

         - Answer either **<kbd>A</kbd>** or **<kbd>Y</kbd>**
      4. Reboot
2. **If the HDD boot order was modified:**

   - Correct the order in the BIOS/UEFI firmware